# Determining if series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The Series is

[image]

For this series the ratio test is inconclusive. I have rewritten the series as

[image]

Currently i am approaching the problem using limit test.
[image]

I couldn't progress from this point. 
Any help or hints are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

I think you could use [Raabe's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html).

Answer (score 0):

The terms decrease each step by a factor $2n/(2n+3)$.
So their logarithm decreases by $\frac{3}{2n}+O(n^{-2})$.
The logarithm of the $n^{th}$ term is around $-\frac{3}{2}\log n$, 
and the term itself is around $n^{-3/2}$.
I think the original sum ought to converge.